# UICollectionView didSelectRowAt is never called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to select one cell in my UICollectionView , I've done everything including setting up the delegate and data source, I have no tap gesture recognisers on my scroll view.

I had a view inside the scroll view which I subclassed as a UIControl to handle when a user taps the screen to exit from the keyboard, but I removed that too and didSelectItemAt is still not firing.
here is my code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var templatesCollection: UICollectionView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        templatesCollection.delegate = self
        templatesCollection.dataSource = self
    }

    extension AddCardViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource
{


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return templates.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = templatesCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "template", for: indexPath) as! TemplateCollectionViewCell
        cell.templateView.text = templates[indexPath.row]
        cell.alignTextVertically()
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = false

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("shfgdsfgidks")
    }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("Deselected")
        }

    }
```

Also this is worth mentioning that the collection view is displaying the data so I know cellForItemAt function is firing at least, its only the didSelectItemAt thats not called.

User Interaction is enabled for both the collectionView and its cell.
also, here's a pic of my hierarchy

[image]

Comment: So you have a view with a full screen collection view in it, no other scroll view, no tap gesture recognisers anywhere? no subviews added to collection view?

Comment: I wrote it myself.

Comment: @AkshayRaina In the Storyboard, please check that `User Interaction Enabled` is ticked for both the `UICollectionView` and the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: No, actually I have a scroll view with a sign Up form and in the end I have a horizontally scrollable collection view, No tap gesture recognizers anywhere and the Collection view cell has one textView inside

Comment: @RhuariGlen , Yes everything is enabled, it still isn't working

Comment: The scrollview is probably soaking up all interactions. I think I have a solution for you

Comment: Please Explain @Scriptable

Comment: @AkshayRaina You are not getting the click as the click is going for TextView. If you need to get action on didSelect then disable user interaction for TextView which is inside the  cell

Comment: @ParthDhorda that did it ! Thats a lot ! I've been going at this for hours now and never realised the solution was soo obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, here is the fix,
As Parth suggested, I was not getting the click as the click is going for TextView. I had to disable user interaction for TextView which is inside the cell to register clicks on the cell.

Answer (score 2):

So `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` both inherit from `UIScrollView` and should not be placed within another scrollView. Apple suggests this is a bad idea and will cause issues. So the best answer is to not do it that way.

Usually if you need to do this, your normally best embedding a `UICollectionView` within a `UITableViewCell` to create your layout. Without knowing exactly what your trying to do it's hard to suggest best approach

If you *must* do it this way then you need to look at [UIGestureRecogniserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate) and configure certain gestures that they can both recognise at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom view in the collection view cell then set isUserInteractionEnabled = false